# HOW TO: Adobe Animate - gotoAndStop(); on a button click

Tags: javascript, flash, animation, adobe

I have created a project in .fla that was exporting to .swf however I now require it in HTML5 format. So I change the file conversion type and now require my ActionScript3 to be converted to JavaScript. However, This is not my strong suit.

I am currently trying:

```
this.stop();

this.close1_btn.addEventListener("click", function (closebtn)
{
this.gotoAndPlay(1);
});

this.store1_btn.addEventListener("click", function (store1_btn)
{
this.gotoAndPlay(11);    
});

this.store2_btn.addEventListener("click", function (store2_btn)
{
this.gotoAndPlay(12);
});

this.store3_btn.addEventListener("click", function (store3_btn)
{
this.gotoAndPlay(13);    
});
```

OVERVIEW: trying to listen to a symbol e.g close1_btn for clicks. when clicked it will link to and stop at a specified frame.

I expect a few bits to be wrong *maybe near the function () part?

Its a fairly simple map so shouldn't be too hard for someone who knows what they are looking at! Thanks so much for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is the function scope, which is a common mistake.

The `addEventListener` method has no implied scope, so the functions will get called on window. If you output `this` in your console when those buttons are clicked, you will probably see `Window`. To solve this, you can:

1. Bind your methods ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind))

Example:

```
this.close1_btn.addEventListener("click", function (closebtn)
{
this.gotoAndPlay(1);
}.bind(this));
```

2. Use the CreateJS `on` shortcut, which takes a 3rd parameter ([docs](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/EventDispatcher.html#method_on))

Example:

```
this.close1_btn.on("click", function (closebtn)
{
this.gotoAndPlay(1);
}, this);
```

One important note is that if you play frame 0 again, that frame script will run again, adding another listener to each button each time, resulting in the functions called multiple times when a button is clicked. I recommend something this this:

```
if (!this.inited) {
  // Your code

  this.inited = true;
}
```

Comment: Hi Lanny,

Thanks for your response.

I am now using the code you provided

'code'
this.stop();

if (!this.inited) {
  // Your code

 
this.close1_btn.addEventListener("click", function (closebtn)
{
this.gotoAndPlay(1);
}.bind(this));

this.store1_btn.addEventListener("click", function (store1btn)
{
this.gotoAndPlay(11);
}.bind(this));
 
 
  this.inited = true;
}
'code'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.

I am now using the code you provided:

```
this.stop();

if (!this.inited) {
  // Your code


this.close1_btn.addEventListener("click", function (closebtn)
{
this.gotoAndPlay(1);
}.bind(this));

this.store1_btn.addEventListener("click", function (store1btn)
{
this.gotoAndStop(11);
}.bind(this));


this.inited = true;
}
```

However, I get this in the output

WARNINGS:
Frame numbers in EaselJS start at 0 instead of 1. For example, this affects gotoAndStop and gotoAndPlay calls. (5)
Content with both Bitmaps and Buttons may generate local security errors in some browsers if run from the local file system.

Any further advice you could give would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

cheers for your continued assistance!

The preview doesn't work when it opens in my browser, is this just because I haven't exported it fully and hosted it online?

So I can ignore these errors?

^^ if that's all cleared up. Do you have recommended way to export and host it on a webpage?

Thanks again buddy, appreciate it!